# C++ 2D Vector Declaration

Tags: c++, vector, 2d-vector

I am doing a homework and I see this vector declaration. I tried to find on Gooogle but still could not understand it. Here it is:

```
     vector<vector<int>>res = vector<vector<int>>(n,vector<int>(n,0));
```

I know `vector<vector<int>>` means 2D vector but I don't understand the part after this `= vector<vector<int>>(n,vector<int>(n,0));`

Comment: When you write `vector<vector<int>>res = vector<vector<int>>(n,vector<int>(n,0))`, the right side means that you are creating a vector of size `n` where each element is a vector of size `n` where all elements are 0.

Comment: The first `n` after `=` declares `n` vectors of type `vector<int>`. The second part, i.e. `vector<int>(n, 0)` declares a vector of size `n` and fills all `n` elements with zeroes. Thus, the first part will declare `n` vectors that are of size `n` with all zeroes as elements.

Comment: You don't really need this, you can write `vector<vector<int>> res(n,vector<int>(n,0))`.

Comment: `res` is a value of `vector<vector<int>>` type, '=' is assignment operator and `vector<vector<int>>(n,vector<int>(n,0))` is object of a `vector<vector<int>>` class initialization with call to  constructor. What is happening: (will read statement from right to left), temporary variable of type `vector<vector<int>>` created, then it assigned (copyed) to the `res` variable of the same type.

Comment: I got it, thank you all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write like this too:

```
vector<vector<int>>res(n,vector<int>(n,0));
```

It means you have n `vector<int>` where each of them has `n` elements initialized to `0`.